# Binomial Proportion Test on test and control populations

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, binomial-distribution, proportion, control-group

I am new to statistical tests and request your help with the following question:

A company wants to test the hypothesis that it's new ad will increase it's total number of subscribers (conversion rate). To test this, 25 percent of customers are randomly assigned to be presented with the company's new ad, whereas the remaining 75 percent are not presented with the new ad. Whether the customer subscribes to the company's contents or not is recorded in each case.
At the end of each day, a manager runs binomial proportion test comparing the conversion rates of the test and control populations using all data gathered since the experiment began. On day 13 the manager reports that the conversion rate in the test population is significantly higher at
the 5% level and recommends that the ad should be shown to all the customers.
Is this the right conclusion? Would you suggest to change something about this experiment's design or the analysis of results?

I have been researching since last many hours, but did not find any useful content  on the Internet about the Binomial Proportion Test for test and control populations. Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Does this relate to class exercise? If yes, please see https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info and add the tag to modify the question accordingly

Comment: Googling [Binomial Proportion Test](https://www.google.com/search?q=Binomial+Proportion+Test) yields very good information at the very top of the list of hits.  However, *this question is not about the test:* it is about interpreting the meaning of "significantly higher than."  For answers, start with the duplicate thread.